# How do I extract a list item from nested json in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json object and I'm trying to extract a couple of values from a nested list. Then print them in markup. I'm getting and error - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

I understand that it's a list and I can't preform a get. I've been searching for the proper method for a few hours now and I'm running out of steam. I'm able to get the Event, but not Value1 and Value2.

This is the json object

```
{
"resource": {
    "data": {
        "event": "qwertyuiop",
        "eventVersion": "1.05",
        "parameters": {
            "name": "sometext",
            "othername": [
                ""
            ],
            "thing": {
                "something": {
                    "blah": "whatever"
                },
                "abc": "123",
                "def": {
                    "xzy": "value"
                }
            },
            "something": [
                "else"
            ]
        },
        "whatineed": [{
            "value1": "text.i.need",
            "value2": "text.i.need.also"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my function

```
def parse_json(json_data: dict) -> Info:
    some_data = json_data.get('resource', {})
    specific_data = some_data.get('data', {})
    whatineed_data = specific_data.get('whatineed', {})

    formatted_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)

    description = f'''
h3. Details
*Event:* {some_data.get('event')}
*Value1:* {whatineed_data('value1')}
*Value2:* {whatineed_data('value2')}
'''
```

Comment: is there a reason `whatineed` is a list?  Can you ever expect it to have more than one item?

Comment: I have no control over the json that's delivered to me. I just need to parse those two values out of it.

Comment: Ok, no problem. My answer is going to depend on whether or not you ever expect to get multiple items in the `whatineed` list.  Do you know if you are only ever going to get one item (or if you will only care about the first answer anyway).

Comment: The two answers that just got posted by others show what I was going to do if you can assume you are only getting (or caring) about the first item in that list.

Comment: No, it will always be a single item

Answer (score 0):

From the data structure, `whatineed` is a `list` with a single item, which in turn is a dictionary. So, one way to access it would be:

```
whatineed_list = specific_data.get('whatineed', [])
whatineed_dict = whatineed_list[0]
```

At this point you can do:

```
value1 = whatineed_dict.get('value1')
value2 = whatineed_dict.get('value2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to the following:

```
def parse_json(json_data: dict) -> Info:
    some_data = json_data.get('resource')
    specific_data = some_data.get('data', {})
    whatineed_data = specific_data.get('whatineed', {})

    formatted_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)
    description = '''
h3. Details
*Event:* {}
*Value1:* {}
*Value2:* {}
'''.format(some_data.get('data').get('event'),whatineed_data[0]['value1'], whatineed_data[0]['value2'])
```

Since `whatineed_data` is a list, you need to index the element first

Answer (score 0):

Python handles json as strings unless they are coming directly from a file. This could be the source for some of your problems. Also [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-parse-data-from-json-into-python) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "whatineed" attribute is really a list, and it's elements are dicts, you can't call whatineed.get asking for Value1 or Value2 as if they are attributes, because it is a list and it don't have attributes.

So, you have two options:

1. If whatineed list has a single element ever, you can access this element directly and than access the element attributes:

```
element = whatineed[0]
v1 = element.get('value1', {})
v2 = element.get('value2', {})
```

2. Or, if whatineed list can have more items, so, you will need to iterate over this list and access those elements:

```
for element in whatineed:
   v1 = element.get('value1', {})
   v2 = element.get('value2', {})
   ## Do something with values
```